# MySQL: Count unique pairs of values in rows

Tags: mysql, select, count, unique

I'm stuck with a problem I don't know how to solve. Here's what my table 'myTable' look like:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| one      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| two      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM myTable; 

+----+-----------------+------------+
| id | one             | two        |
+----+-----------------+------------+
|  1 | cat             | steve      |
|  2 | cat             | steve      |
|  3 | cat             | adam       |
|  4 | dog             | john       |
|  5 | dog             | adam       |
|  6 | dog             | alice      |
|  7 | mouse           | peter      |
|  8 | mouse           | peter      |
|  9 | mouse           | peter      |
+----+-----------------+------------+
```

What I'm after is a query that for each unique value in 'one' gives me the count of unique values in 'two', i.e. that gives me:
dog   3 (three unique names)
cat   2 (two unique names)
mouse 1 (one unique name)

I have searched around, but don't know how to find the right answer, and gotten as far as:

```
SELECT one, two, COUNT(two) AS nr FROM myTable GROUP BY one, two ORDER BY one;
```

Any suggestions much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you need to count distinct name you need to use `distinct` keyword.

Try this query

```
select 
   one,  
   count(distinct two) as cnt 
from 
   tbl 
group by 
   one
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaeee/1)**

```
|   ONE | CNT |
---------------
|   cat |   2 |
|   dog |   3 |
| mouse |   1 |
```

Comment: Thanks Meherzad, worked beautifully and saved me more than a few grey hairs!!